# How to count number of occurrences in a list and match them with the item?

Tags: java, arraylist

So I'm trying to extract the names of Data type from myStocks list and match them with the number of occurrences, displaying them in a GraphicsText Object. (Ford : 1, Gap : 2 etc.) Here's the code I have so far but it doesn't seem to work. Please help me out

```
private void updatePortfolio()    {
    ArrayList<String> listToDisplay = new ArrayList<>();
    if(!myStocks.isEmpty()) {
        for (Data myStock : myStocks) {
            listToDisplay.add(myStock.getName());
            for(String stock: listToDisplay) {
                int occurrences = Collections.frequency(listToDisplay, stock);
                displayPortfolio.setText("You Currently Own: " + listToDisplay + " " + occurrences);
                System.out.println(stock + occurrences);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What are the contents of `myStocks`, and what result did you expect and what did you obtain?

Comment: I recommend you take a look at the stream grouping collectors. I suspect you need something like `myStocks.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Data::getName, Collectors.counting()))`

Comment: Yes that worked @sprinter, thank you so much!